# How to change apple ID while it has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I just bought apple iPhone 4s from my friend but it throw an error "**This Apple ID has been disabled for security reasons**" is it possible that i change apple ID during this state? Or  is there any other way to change it?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts2446), it may be a case of entering the password incorrectly too many times, in which case you can try resetting the password at Apple's [iForgot](https://iforgot.apple.com) site.

Another option, if you don't have any purchases linked to that Apple ID, is creating a new one using a different email address. You just have to sign out of the current Apple ID (if that's even necessary) and sign up for a new one. All of that is done from within Settings -> iTunes & App Store, although the sign up process might be easier to do on a computer with a real keyboard, from within iTunes (Store menu -> Create Apple ID...)

Comment: somehow iPhone not allowed me to enter into settings option because i just it and after restarting a message pop up "Please enter your apple ID to unlock it" is there any other way or i just lost my money :(

Comment: @Adi, it sounds like Activation Lock has been enabled. That means the phone may have been stolen and could explain why it's locked the Apple ID (the thief may have tried excessively to enter in various passwords). There is no way to bypass this feature. You'll have to contact the seller as perhaps they simply forgot (or didn't know) to disable Find my iPhone). More details can be found here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5818